2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #5 on Blender has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:


They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Thank you both for participating and congrats on wining. Also thanks to Allen Simpson for nominating

Welcome on board and thank you to all candidates and voters!

So where do i deposit the hush money?

Congratulations to you both! And thanks to @Allen Simpson also.

Congratulations !

Congrats you two
